# Create a method to change the volume of the headphones, java class

Tags: java, methods, netbeans

This is only my second coding course, but I am loving everything about it. However, I am having trouble with creating a final method before I can turn it in. The program runs perfectly fine as of now, but I need to create a method called changeVolume(value) that *changes the volume of the headphone to the value passed into the method.* I feel like I am overthinking it, but I cannot seem to create any portion of code to switch the "volume level" for the headphones. Any help would be appreciated, but I need to step away for a bit and rest my eyes so I thought I would reach out for some help before I do!

[image]

**The picture above is my program running**

The following code below is my class HeadPhone.java, and the main class (TestHeadPhone.java) is where everything will be called. I left out getters/setters and a lot of other things so I hope this gives a good idea. If not, just let me know and I will share any portion of code you need!

```
//Constants defined
int LOW = 1;
int MEDIUM = 2;
int HIGH = 3;

//Private data fields 
private int volume;
private String manufacturer;
private String headPhoneModel;
private Color headPhoneColor;
private boolean pluggedIn = false;

//Default constructor for default headphones 
public HeadPhone () {
    volume = MEDIUM;
    manufacturer = "Apple";
    headPhoneModel = "Air Pods";
    headPhoneColor = Color.WHITE;
    pluggedIn = false;
    }//End default constructor

    //toString method
    public String toString(){
        return "\n------Your current headphones are------ " + "\n"
                +"Volume Level: " + volume + "\n"
                +"Headphone Manufacturer: " + manufacturer + "\n"
                +"Model of Headphones: " + headPhoneModel + "\n" 
                +"Color of Headphones: " + headPhoneColor + "\n"
                +"The headphones are plugged in: " + pluggedIn;
    }//End toString
```

Comment: `I left out getters/setters` - well maybe there is a setter to change the volume?

Comment: This looks like Java code. What does this have to do with Javascript? Please remove the Javascript tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set the volume:

```
volume = "The volume";
```

(And can you show more code to understand entierly how youtr program is working? so add the main mathod to your post so I can understand better wath you are tring to achive)